# Client local time on server

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, timezone, utc

My client and server are on different timezone, all the date in DB are stored in UTC. We want to generate the report on the server with the client time not the UTC time.

When ever `new Date(UTCDate)` is create UTC is converted into Server Datetime instead of Client with timezone offset.

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment.js library to handle the date and timezone related tasks.
Refer [here](https://momentjs.com/guides/) for more info.

Comment: how moment can help in this task? will you please elaborate